# How to get different images to display for different EditText inputs?

Tags: android, image, imageview, visibility

I have an `ImageView` in my XML code and want to have the picture in the `ImageView` change depending on the input in an `EditText` box. How can I do this? The following if else clause gives me an error and my app crashes.

```
else if(compare.equalsIgnoreCase("sweet shoppe")){
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
            image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
```

in Layout...

```
 <ImageView 
     android:id="@+id/image1"
     android:layout_below="@id/answer"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
     android:gravity="center" 
     android:src="@drawable/sweet"
     android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Comment: Can you please put the error log here?

Comment: Please post some more code with your error.

Comment: You want different images or a fix image to display ? From ur code it looks like fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare your String of `EditText` using `getText()` method as below. You can not directly compare the value of your `EditText`. To get the value of `EditText` you need to get it using `getText()` method which will return the text.

Supposing that your `compare` is `EditText` only.

```
    else if(compare.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("sweet shoppe")){
         ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
        image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `src` and `visibility` from XML imageView and set image in ImageView run time

Here compare is String get from `EditText`

Try below code

`else if(compare.equalsIgnoreCase("sweet shoppe")){`
`ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);`
        `img.setImageResource(R.drawable.sweet);`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code block to handle your issue

---

layout.java extends activity file content

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        txt.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                        && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    EditText tx = (EditText) v;
                    String editBoxTxt = tx.getText().toString();

                    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
                    if (editBoxTxt.equalsIgnoreCase("ring")) {
                        img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ring);
                    } else
                        img.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

---

layout.xml file content
-->

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ***compare.equalsIgnoreCase("sweet shoppe")*** use like this, this may help you.

```
else if(compare.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("sweet shoppe").trim()){
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
        image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
```